# How to list all folders in a ftp directory?

Tags: python, ftp, download, ftplib

I am trying to list the folders in a [ftp directory](ftp://atlas.ca.gov/pub/naip/2012/doqqs_combined_color-nir/) so that the output is as follows:

```
[32114, 32115, 32116, ..., 42123]
```

The following script accesses the ftp site.  How can I access the folders in the ftp directory using the attached script as a start?

```
import arcpy, ftplib, os, socket

HOST = 'atlas.ca.gov'
DIRN = '/pub/naip/2012/doqqs_combined_color-nir/'
workspace = 'F:/download/location'

# Get current working directory
print 'The current working directory is %s' % os.getcwd()

# Change the current working directory to a download folder
os.chdir(workspace)
print 'The workspace has been changed to %s' % workspace 

try:
    f = ftplib.FTP(HOST)
except (socket.error, socket.gaierror), e:
    print 'ERROR: cannot reach "%s"' % HOST
print '*** Connected to host "%s"' % HOST

try:     
    f.login()
except ftplib.error_perm:
    print 'Error: cannot login anonymously'
    f.quit()
print '*** Logged in as "anonymous"'

try:
    f.cwd(DIRN)
except ftplib.error_perm:
    print 'ERROR: cannot CD to "%s"' % DIRN
    f.quit()
print '*** Changed to "%s" folder' % DIRN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the answer by abarnert, the following produces the list:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('atlas.ca.gov')
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('/pub/naip/2012/doqqs_combined_color-nir/')
print ftp.nlst()
```

[image]

Comment: Anyway to get file list from subfolders too?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [`ftplib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) docs, there are two obvious functions for this: `nlst` and `dir`.

Either one will give you a list of *all* members in the directory, both files and subdirectories.

With `nlst`, you don't get any information beyond the name. But if you were planning to `chdir` or otherwise use each one of them, that's OK; you will get exceptions for the ones that turned out to be regular file, and can just skip over them.

With `dir`, you get a full directory listing, in human-readable form. Which you will have to capture (by passing a `callback` function) and then parse manually—which is a lot less fun, but the only way you can know in advance which members are files and which are directories.

Answer (score 1):

If the server is a windows machine, the output of
`ftp.dir()` will look like `01-14-14  04:21PM       <DIR>          Output`

If the server is of the *nix variety, the output will look like `drwx------   3 user group        512 Apr 22  2005 Mail`

If you want to check if an item is a directory, use a regular expression on each line.
Windows FTP server will contain `<DIR>` if the item is a directory and *nix ftp servers will start with `d`.

Do you need help with Python regexes?